# Elasticsearch tire gem. How can search for '&', and what analyzer i have to use in-order to index '&' .?

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I am using tire gem in `elasticsearch` in application.

When search for '&' or any '&' contained name, its not returning any results.

Please tell me a way to achieve this.

Comment: can you give an example of the search and the data?

Comment: Data is the name of the products that are there in my application... and i am searching for "Black & white lined kurta"...there are many such products in my app...My mapping...    indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball', boost: 100, settings:{ type: "custom",tokenizer: "standard",filter: []}

Comment: I'm looking at something similar involving $ and £. There is [some documentation on ampersands](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html) in custom analyzer and filter though

Answer (score 0):

The [lucene documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters) does not mention a single `&` as a special character:

> Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query
>   syntax. The current list special characters are
>
> `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \`

Also see my comment.